# How do you use csslint from the command line?

Tags: css, bash, ubuntu, continuous-integration, csslint

I'm new to Ubuntu, I'll be the first to admit that, but I need to integrate `csslint` into a CI build script and I found the about page on the `csslint` site unhelpful.  It gave me two options for installing `csslint` but they require either `node` or `rhino`:

```
Node.js:
sudo npm install -g csslint

Rhino.js:
java -jar rhino.jar csslint-rhino.js --rules= ~ /* suppressed for simplicity */
```

After googling for either of these in a format I know how to work with,  on google groups I found someone asking a similar question. The answer was that `rhino` is not a ready made product you install and run but a library you work with.

All I need to do is:

- pass CSS files to `csslint` through bash with `csslint` args
- get the response back
- evaluate whether or not the build should fail due to violations

Is there anywhere I can find step-by-step instructions that include dependencies such as `node` or `rhino`?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Found the answer myself and decided to put it here to help others.
>
> sudo apt-get install npm
>
> sudo npm install -g csslint
>
> csslint pathtofile.css
>
> have feelings hurt.

Comment: Thanks Andy, wasn't sure if I could do that.